# Deduce type from (member) function

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

Is there a simple way to deduce the "type" of a member function? I would like to deduce the type of the following (member) function:

```
struct Sample {
  void func(int x) { ... }
};

void func(int x) { ... }
```

To the following type (to be used in `std::function`):

```
void(int)
```

I'm looking for a solution that does support a variable count (not varargs!) of arguments...

**EDIT - Example:**

I'm looking for an expression similar to `decltype` - let's call it `functiontype` - that has the following semantics:

```
functiontype(Sample::func) <=> functiontype(::func) <=> void(int)
```

`functiontype(expr)` should evaluate to a type that is compatible with `std::function`.

Comment: Overloaded functions kill your dream.

Comment: @Xeo: I agree, but let's assume that this is used in a context without overloaded functions...

Comment: @juanchopanza: I know, but it's "interface" is [for what this is intended for atleast]

Comment: @Xeo which makes me think "here is another compile-time reflection feature we need" -- being able to iterate/list the overrides of a given function somehow.  It would have to iterate over both function templates and functions sadly (as function template instantiations are not iterable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    void f(double) { }
};

void f(double) { }

template<typename T>
struct function_type { };

template<typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
struct function_type<R (T::*)(Args...)>
{
    typedef function<R(Args...)> type;
};

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct function_type<R(*)(Args...)>
{
    typedef function<R(Args...)> type;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(
        is_same<
            function_type<decltype(&A::f)>::type, 
            function<void(double)>
            >::value,
        "Error"
        );

    static_assert(
        is_same<
            function_type<decltype(&f)>::type, 
            function<void(double)>
            >::value,
        "Error"
        );
}
```

Comment: And again, overloaded functions kill your dreams. :3

Comment: @Xeo: "let's assume that this is used in a context without overloaded functions..." - The OP doesn't have dreams! ;-)